# h:outputLabel position within a h:panelGroup

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code in a xhtml page using PrimeFaces:

```
<h:panelGroup id="dropZoneId" layout="block" 
              style="height:500px;width:1210px;text-align:center;">
    <h:outputLabel value="Drop here" style= "color: azure;" />    
</h:panelGroup>
```

I would like to have the `<h:outputLabel>` "drop here" in the middle of the `<h:panelGroup>` but so far I can only put it at the center at the top of the `<h:panelGroup>` with no css.

Can someone please help ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will suffice:

```
<h:panelGroup id="dropZoneId" layout="block" style="height: 500px; text-align: center">
    <h:outputText value="Drop here" style="color: azure; position: absolute; top: 240px" />    
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: thank you. it is working for outputText and outputLabel.

Answer (score 0):

```
.myLabel {
    float: center;
}
```

Official Resource #Primefaces: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=14611